# Ways to see a list of all the tabs open in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

You know how when you get to 10+ tabs open in your browser (in this case Chrome) and you can't tell which tab is which anymore? I'm sure there are some good extension or something - what's the best solution to this problem?

[image]

Comment: you can identify some of them, obviously, via the favicons.

Comment: yeah but if i have 20 links on the site open, that's not much help

Comment: This topic explains how to find the list of tabs using Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915370/retrieving-which-tabs-are-open-in-chrome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of 2021, there is a ***native*** Chrome feature that allows you to scroll through all of your open chrome tabs (as well as some recently closed ones).

To access it, click on the dropdown arrow next to the minimize tab button.
[image]

It will open up a scrollable dropdown with all tabs open in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: This is just amazing, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: hotkey: ``Ctrl+Shift+A``

Answer (score 84):

Start Chrome's task manager, and then you can double click on the title of whatever tab you need.

#### Microsoft Windows

Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the Chrome task manager.

Alternatively, on Chrome's `More tools` menu, select `Task manager` [(source)](https://www.lifewire.com/using-task-manager-in-chrome-446159)

#### Mac OS X

On the Chrome `Window` menu, select `Task Manager`.

#### ChromeOS

Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to bring up the Chrome task manager.

Alternatively, on Chrome's `More tools` menu, select `Task manager` [(source)](https://www.lifewire.com/using-task-manager-in-chrome-446159)

Comment: Thanks!  I'm in a VDI environment, and all my extensions are unavailable due to a synchronization problem.  It's good to see a built-in solution.  Normally, I would be using [Session Buddy](http://www.sessionbuddy.com) to manage this.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this solution does show you all tabs across all instances of Chrome, different profiles or otherwise. I have three profiles running at work, and that makes the task manager a bit overloaded with unrelated tab groups. Could be very useful for those that do want this behavior, of course.

Comment: This does not work in Chrome on Mac OSX (Yosemite).

Comment: Though Chrome's Task Manager still exists on OSX and presumably all we would need to do is add a key binding for it.

Comment: VERY helpful: **double-click on the tab title**

Comment: On Mac OS X, to add shortcut, check this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/xz-9TlEwwCc

Comment: Chrome is a bit more careful about wasting system resources these days. The list is no longer complete. Unused tabs disappear from the it after a while.

Answer (score 76):

This works in all versions of Chrome, on Mac, Linux and Windows:

```
chrome://inspect/#pages
```

[image: Chrome inspect tabs screenshot]

Unfortunately, this won't show tabs that haven't been used in a while. But for recent tabs, no need to install any extension, and you can also search in the tab names - great when you have many tabs. To open a tab, just click Inspect.

Comment: I know this wasn't in the original question, but is there a way to open the tab from the Inspect Pages page?

Comment: @wisbucky: of course, you click Inspect. (You can close the Inspect side bar by pressing F12 on Windows or Cmd + Opt + I on Mac).

Comment: Ah, I found the issue. It doesn't switch tabs if Chrome Developer Tools is undocked. After I redocked CDT, then this method worked.

Comment: "Yuck", unfortunately it opens the entire inspect element screen over my screen and many more keystrokes required, but OK for extensionless.

Comment: This was very useful to me for getting a text list of all of the tabs open in Chrome. Use it after teaching a class and opening a bunch of tabs to collect that list for easily sharing. Thanks

Comment: Does not work for Chrome on `iPad`. It's the latest build at this time of writing. `chrome://inspect` gives... "**This site can't be reached** The webpage at chrome://inspect/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Comment: Just like the task manager, this does not list tabs which haven't been used for a while (as of 2018).

Answer (score 29):

Install [TabsOutliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl?hl=en) extension -

The ultimate windows & tabs manager for Chrome:

[image]

Not only it is show all the tabs and windows, it allow to add notes to them, freely reorganize everything, rescue all of this on Chrome crashes and give possibility to unload tabs without deleting them from tree - "in place" - very cool and handy, a lifesaver for me, and for any other tab addict.

Comment: What's cool: it supports splitting and merging groups of tabs into windows.

Comment: For me, this appears better than Vimium. Both Chrome store pages provide explanatory videos. The videos appear to say that Vimium provides a simple list, while TabsOutliner offers hierarchical (i.e., outline) structure. In the list, tabs opened from a page become a subset of that page. A new Chrome window has its own new list. You can still have the list even with no Chrome windows open, and can restore only selected tabs if desired. And more.

Comment: @RayWoodcock I use TabsOutliner *and* Vimium - `shift-f` in Vimium finds a tab quickly, as well as all the other stuff, and TabsOutliner allows me to organise, close, sleep and copy tabs.

Comment: In TabsOutliner I particularly like the way you can copy tabs to text with `ctrl+c` or right-click, copy; in a format that is almost Markdown syntax, which I can paste into my notes which are Markdown format. I then have to add square brackets around the page title manually to make it a link in, or I made a Chrome extension to do this: [drkvogel/linkify](https://github.com/drkvogel/linkify)

Answer (score 23):

I've been using the [Quick Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-tabs/jnjfeinjfmenlddahdjdmgpbokiacbbb) extension for a while, does a good job.

[image: Quick Tabs]

Comment: This one would have been perfect if it weren't so slow :(

Comment: i've been using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabman-tabs-manager/hgmnkflcjcohihpdcniifjbafcdelhlm which is a pretty similar solution. maybe won't be as slow for you?

Comment: Nice, I added `ctrl+q` as the shortcut for this in chrome://extensions/

Comment: Quick Tabs is fantastic.  Using this with `Ctrl-Space` will drastically improve my productivity in the browser.

Comment: Take a look at [Taptab](https://crx.dam.io/ext/dlcdopfmnappdjilkgaaajocplcjnnlg.html). It's the simplest solution for the problem. Just a button that drops down the list of tabs for the window. Now it's archived so, it's a bit more difficult to install, but worth it.

Comment: I had to wait for about 40 secs for this to bring up the list of tabs 63 tabs. Needless to say it's unusable like this.

Comment: It allows to [assign hotkeys](https://www.howtogeek.com/127162/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-browser-actions-and-extensions-in-google-chrome/) for tabs popup and prev/next tab switch in LRU order.

Comment: Can I recommend [QuicKey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) instead of "Quick Tabs"? It's super slick and responsive, it looks better IMO, it has its own hotkeys, and the developer is very responsive on GitHub. Quick Tabs is... very bloated IIRC, to the point where it kept causing system freezes.

Answer (score 16):

The Chrome extension called [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/details?hl=en) will let you search and go to any of your open tabs if you press <kbd>T</kbd>, amongst many other things that it can do.

http://vimium.github.io

Comment: This is the best option for me, thanks! No extra extensions except Vimium. **"amongst many other things that it can do."** - YES, it does!

Comment: This is the best options! Still!

Answer (score 12):

***Mac OS X (with trackpad)***

In the search bar write:

`about:flags`

and click enter. Now enable Tab Overview.

[image: Tab Overview]

A three-finger swipe will now reveal something like this:

[image: More tabs]

Here's 20 tabs for good measure:

[image: 20 tabs]

It works really well. I can't browse without it these days.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to use this in Windows?

Comment: @nhinkle: Not sure sorry. It'd be a shame if it didn't work in Windows. I've only tried in OS X.

Comment: @nhinkle There doesn't seem to be AFAIK

Comment: Looks useful, but sadly this doesn't work on Mountain Lion. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-discuss/TVhiIaeQhIg

Comment: I cant find this option in yosemite

Comment: This is gone now. Removed per chrome devs. https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?revision=251439&view=revision

Comment: @gooddadmike any chrome base alternative?

Answer (score 3):

Type `about:flags` into the address bar, and then enable Side Tabs:

> Adds a "Use Side Tabs" entry to the tab strip's context menu. Use this to toggle between tabs on top (default) and tabs on the side. Useful on widescreen monitors.

[image]

Comment: I was not able to find any "Side Tabs" menu in the latest chrome versions. Can you elaborate your method a little more. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like this experimental feature was dropped at some point.

Comment: I can't find this option

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer an overview of the windows as columns, especially on a wider screen. I used to use Cluster, but because of lack of support I have now switched to the TabManager.io Chrome extension.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another altenative with expose-like functionality:

[TooManyTabs For Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp)

[Features](http://blog.visibotech.com/p/toomanytabs-for-chrome.html) include:

- Bird's eye view of all opened tabs
- Clear preview of each tab's content (fills up gradually as you use)
- Instant tab search
- Sort tabs by creation time, domain or title
- Restore recently closed tabs
- Suspend idle tabs and save memory, organize with custom columns
- Custom themes

---

**Bonus**

[How to Create Custom Keyboard Shortcuts For Any Extension in Google Chrome](https://www.howtogeek.com/127162/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-browser-actions-and-extensions-in-google-chrome/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to History. There you'll see the list of opened tabs if you have synced chrome with google account on both the computers.

Answer (score 0):

my favourite chrome app for listing all tabs: [fast tab switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fast-tab-switcher/jkhfenkikopkkpboaipgllclaaehgpjf).

Answer (score 0):

The [OneTab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en) is pretty great.  It consolidates all tabs into a single tab that then acts as a dynamic tab manager page so you can reorder, reopen, close, save, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple extension: [console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/console/nbjjflbnekmabedahdolabcpahfjojjb)

- It's lightweight
- Completely free

for watch tab's title

> typing: `list` or `ls` on the input box. done! (clear screen `cls`)

There are some other features. If you are interested, you can download and typing the `help` to see.

Answer (score 0):

May be will be useful for somebody...

As of version 120 of Chrome, they moved all tabs drop down from the right (near minimize, split and close buttons) to the very left side before the first tab. Good that short cut is still the same **Ctrl + Shift + A**

[image]