# How to find out which of the Chrome sessions is playing sounds? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, audio, task-manager, session

I found this question:

[How can I find out which tab is playing music?](https://superuser.com/q/414504/730576)

but it is an old question that does not solve my problem, which is very similar - or even the same - but the answers there do not work.

I am using this version of [Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/1161596/730576):
[image]

I normally have many [chrome sessions](https://superuser.com/q/290758/730576) open. 
for example:
[image]

and here on the [task bar](https://superuser.com/q/947505/730576):
[image]

and here a partial view of the [task manager](https://superuser.com/questions/199148/run-task-manager-as-another-user-administrator):

[image: hi]

So I have a youtube session somewhere playing a documentary on [Magellan navigation to the East](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU6KFI3tcYE) but I cannot find it.

My computer crashed and after restarting, I started Chrome - restored to the previous sessions - there were lots of them, but I cannot find this particular one. I don't even know if it is active, or just the sound is playing.

How to find out what session is playing sounds, if any?

Comment: Click lock icon in the left side of address bar. If PlaySound is enabled - disable it. If sound stopped - you find it. PS. Disable sound on webpages by default. Enable for separate page if needed.

Comment: it is not clear. where is the lock icon in the left side of the address bar? If you know how to sort this out, please consider answering it. would be helping me and maybe a bunch of other people a lot by showing it.

Comment: *where is the lock icon in the left side of the address bar?* Between address bar where `superuser.com/questions/1509787/...` is shown, and Refresh button. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPLIc.png

Comment: Check out this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1447666/what-chrome-tab-has-just-made-noise